# Basic Tutorial for node.js openCV

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-recognition

I'm searching for a basic tutorial to use OpenCV with node.js. I couldn't find anything describing the functionality so perhaps anybody can give me an hint where I can find such information.
Hope anybody has an idea
Daniel

Answer (score 4):

There's the [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) module to use OpenCV bindings in node.js. There are some examples in there but I haven't come across any tutorials yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Solution**

I chose to go with a [native module](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and update my bindings.gyp to include and link with ffmpeg/libav* and opencv

```
  'include_dirs+': [
    'src/',
    '<!@(pkg-config --cflags libavutil libavformat libavcodec libswscale )',
    '<!@(pkg-config --cflags opencv )'
  ],
  'link_settings': {
    'libraries': [
      '<!@(pkg-config --libs libavcodec libavformat libswscale libavutil)',
      '<!@(pkg-config --libs opencv)'
    ],
```